# SSIS Script task- how can I give dynamic directory name and file name in script task?

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I am not good at c#. I got script task that deletes the existing file from directory, I got variable that holds both directory value and file value. how can I use those variable values in this code?:

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            string directoryPath = @"\\sql\sqlfiles;
            string[] oldFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "MYDBFULL_*.bak");
            foreach (string currFile in oldFiles)
            {
                FileInfo currFileInfo = new FileInfo(currFile);
                currFileInfo.Delete();

            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

I want to use variable value here at `@"\\sql\sqlfiles` and `MYDBFULL_*.bak`

Thnak you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found Ans. For anybody for future ref:

Since my variables are dynamic, means every time it changes its values. In script task take those as read and write variables.
and add this code.

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            string directoryPath = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFilePath"].Value.ToString();
            string[] oldFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value.ToString());
            foreach (string currFile in oldFiles)
            {
                FileInfo currFileInfo = new FileInfo(currFile);
                currFileInfo.Delete();

            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

hope this helps.